# JavaScript I'm trying to code hangman game only JavaScript no HTML "I just started to learn JavaScript"

Tags: javascript

```
var words = ["cat", "dog", "house", "mouse", "phone"];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var guesses = 10;
console.log("you have " + guesses + " guesses\nthe word is:")
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
   console.log("*")      
   
}
```

but the it prints:     //if the word is length = 3

you have 10 guesses
the word is:
*
*
*

I want this to be like this

you have 10 guesses
the word is:
*
*
*
I have searched here and found that they are doing something like this:

```
var letters = [];
```

and then add it here:

```
var words = ["cat", "dog", "house", "mouse", "phone"];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var guesses = 10;
console.log("you have " + guesses + " guesses\nthe word is:")
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    letters[i] =("*")      
    
}
```

but I don't know how to print it

Comment: Like `console.log(new Array(word.length).fill("*").join(" "));`?

Comment: Can you edit your post's title to more accurately summarize the *problem* you're having, instead of your desired end product or your level of expertise in a particular language? It will make your post easier to find for not only those who are seeking to help you, but also for future visitors to Stack Overflow who may be encountering similar issues. See: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
var words = ["cat", "dog", "house", "mouse", "phone"];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var guesses = 10;
console.log("you have " + guesses + " guesses\nthe word is:")
console.log(word.split('').map(val => "*").join(" "))
```